# Does zoism mean "approaching a subject from an original angle"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

Example sentence:

> [Zoism.co.uk](http://www.zoism.co.uk/)
>
> Zoism - 'Approaching a subject from an original angle'

However Collins Online Dictionary defines it as:

> [zoism](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/zoism) *noun*
>   1. a reverence for animal life or a belief in magical animal powers
>   2. a doctrine that life is due to a certain vital force

Is **zoism** really a word that means "approaching a subject from an original angle"? If not, is there another word for that concept?

Comment: All the online dictionaries appear to agree with Collins.

Comment: An editor added the *single word* tag. Xatabay, you need to add an example sentence or change that new tag to *phrase request* (see tag description). Also, IMO, this should be two different questions: "What does *zoism* mean?" and "What is a word that means 'approaching [...] angle' ?"

Comment: I think the word "re-imagine" might approach the meaning you're searching for.

Comment: Or "*to think outside the box*"

Comment: Of course the best way to look at something is "*to see all around it*" I.e., to see it from *all* angles not just one or two.

Comment: Stagedoor Publishing appears to be alone on the Internet in attributing any meaning similar to "Approaching a subject from an original angle" to the word _zoism_. Without some further documentation, the posted definition seems highly suspect.

Comment: Perhaps Stagedoor is not defining the word Zoism, but stating: 
"Zoism (the doctrine or just the corporation that owns the website) has the following tagline or goal: approaching a subject from an original angle"
Admittedly, that's a lot for a dash to say.

Comment: There is ever-popular nautical expression: [try a different tack](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/try+a+different+tack).

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Wiktionary agrees largely with Collins Online Dictionary: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zoism

Perhaps an alternative phrase (not word) might be, "To see something from a peculiar perspective".

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything that ends with 'ism' is a specific concept, a certain point of view :
Inter alia : animalism - the doctrine that human beings are purely animal in nature and lacking a spiritual nature
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Isms